# Save state to Database via LINQ using Windows Service

Tags: linq, windows-services, usb

I am working on a project where I read some hardware data from via USB and I need to save the state to a database every second. I want to do this via LINQ, however it seems not to work. It fails to submit changes to database. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    private string connString = "someConnectionString";
    private BMSDataContext BMS_DS;
    private USBConnection USBConn;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       //Connecting to USB device
       USBConn = new USBConnection();
       USBConn.attemptUSBConnection();
       if (USBConn.getConnectionStatus())
             EventLog.WriteEntry("Successfully Connected to USB device", EventLogEntryType.Information);
       else
             EventLog.WriteEntry("Failed to connect to USB device", EventLogEntryType.Error);

       //initialing the DataContext
       BMS_DS = new BMSDataContext(connString);

       System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
       timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.ReadFromUSBAndLog);
       timer.Start();
}

     private void ReadFromUSBAndLog(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
          if (!USBConn.getConnectionStatus())
                   EventLog.WriteEntry("Connection to USB lost!", EventLogEntryType.Error);

          //reading data via USB
          USBConn.receiveViaUSB();

          testLog newRow = new testLog
          {
              value = USBConn.fromDeviceToHostBuffer[1].ToString()
          };

          //THIS IS AS FAR AS IT GOES...
          BMS_DS.testLogs.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);
          //THIS IS NEVER REACHED
          BMS_DS.SubmitChanges();
          EventLog.WriteEntry("Submitted", EventLogEntryType.Information);  
     }
```

Comment: `//THIS IS NEVER REACHED` - So you get an exception? Which one?

Comment: No errors. If I write an Windows Event after each line and start the service, Windows Event Logger will show for every second elapsed, all events before InsertOnSubmit row and nothing after. So if I replace the line that currently holds a comment "THIS IS NEVER REACHED" with a log entry, it does not appear. Also nothing gets saved in the database table. So, for some reason, it gets stuck on adding the new line to pending state to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

OK I was being stupid. It seems that my test table didn't have a Primary Key and the insert was failing because of it. I didn't know this was a requirement. Working fine after adding a identity pk column to the table.

Thanks